# Yii check if the record already exsists in database table

Tags: php, yii, yii-cactiverecord

I've got 2 models (producten and voorraad), and one controller (producten).
So i've build a form inside the producten **C**R**U**D (create/update).
This is a custom form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <span class='btn btn-default addOption'>Optie toevoegen</span>
</div>
<div class='opties'>    

</div>
<div class="form-group">
    Verkrijgbaar als backorder?
    <select name="backorder">
        <option value="1">Ja</option>
        <option value="0">Nee</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This is very easy. If you press on the button `addOption`, it will add a few form inputs.

Now when the form is being saved (here the trouble begins), it will always **add** the data from the form to the database. But i don't want that. I want the data to be checked first, if it already exsists, if so, it has to be **replaced** and not added again.

Is there a yii function for that, or how do I do this?

ProductenController piece:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if(substr($key, 0,5) == 'maat_'){
        $index_expl = explode('_',$key);
        $index = $index_expl['1'];

        $aantal = $_POST['aantal_'.$index];

        $maten = explode(',',$value);
        foreach($maten as $maat_key => $maat){
            $kleuren = explode(',',$_POST['kleur_'.$index]);
                foreach($kleuren as $kleur_key => $kleur){
                    $voorraad = new Voorraad();
                    $voorraad->product_id = $model->id;
                    $voorraad->maat = $maat;
                    $voorraad->kleur = $kleur;
                    $voorraad->aantal = $aantal;
                    $voorraad->backorder = (int)$_POST['backorder'];
                    $voorraad->save();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the following :

```
$voorraad = new Voorraad();
```

with :

```
$voorraad = Voorraad::model()->findByPk($model->id); // assuming id is primary key, you can also use `findByAttributes`
if($voorraad == null) $voorraad = new Voorraad();
```

`$voorraad->save();` is also used for updating the record.

Comment: What do I have to do with else? What does $voorraad has to be then? Because I've tried something simular to this, but I can't get it to get the Voorraad model.

Comment: no `else` required, whatever value you pass, will get updated when you call `save()`. `$voorraad` will always be a model, if `id` is present, existing model, else new model.

Comment: But how does it know it's the voorraad model to call for? Because we are in the ProductenController, not VoorraadController. And we are trying to update VoorraadModel.

Comment: I meant `$voorraad->save();` :)

Comment: We are using `Voorraad::model` and `new Voorraad()` isn't that enough ? `VoorraadController` won't come into picture here. :)

Comment: Omg, totally missed you've changed $voorraad to `Voorraad::model()->findByPk($model->id);` I've used findByAttributes, and it works like a charm now! Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

just put a hidden input field in your form:

```
<div class="form-group hidden">
    <input name="id" value="<?php echo YOURID;?>"/>
</div>
```

check if `id` exist in your server with `empty()`,if not just add;if exist then update.

Comment: I don't think that will work, because the voorraad table can have multiple product_id's in it. For example: If we have 1 pants in color green and size XL, it will add that to database. But if we get another pants in the week after with an other size and/or color, it should be added and not updated.

Comment: `id` is the table's primary key you want to keep data not duplicated .

Comment: I've got a unique ID, but that's AI. It has nothing to do with the size/color combination. Product_id can be in the database table many times. So that one isn't unique either. So I have to check if the color and size combination are in the table with the specified product ID. query would look like: `SELECT * FROM voorraad WHERE maat = '$size' AND color = '$color' AND product_id = '$product_id'`.